# Make firefox more accepting of self-signed SSL certs

Tags: security, ssl, ssl-certificate, firefox

Is there any plugin or setting for firefox that can simplify the invalid SSL certificate process to a single click, or even not put up any errors and just display a warning indicator?

Working on a dev network using self-signed cerificates for initial design means contantly having to go through the 5 step process to grant an exemption for a site, which is a real pain when swapping things around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this addon to change the certificate acceptance behavior in Firefox:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6843

Comment: That add-on was disabled on the Mozilla site... I guess they considered it too great a security risk.

Answer (score 8):

Talk to your sysadmin.  They can setup a CA on your domain (assuming a Windows network here).  Have the dev servers use certs from that internal CA, which will be trusted by all machines on the domain.

Comment: +1 for CA.  You can accomplish a CA certificate setup with openssl.  If that is too daunting you could also use a GUI like TinyCA.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you might want to consider doing is to simply self sign a wildcard certificate for use on your development network.  Then install that wildcard cert on all the systems.  Once you accept the certificate once it should be good everywhere.

Comment: This would work, but setting up a CA and trusting the CA to sign certificates for individual hosts is a better solution.

Comment: @Alex, I agree, but if it is for testing/dev and the network is only going to be around for a short time, then it might not be worth the effort.